# Rails GROUP BY query using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I want to write this query using classic Active Record, instead of raw sql.

```
SELECT

   user_id,
   term, 
   SUM(views) AS Views,
   SUM(clicks) AS Clicks

FROM reports
GROUP BY user_id, term
```

Tried this, but doesn't work.

```
Report.group([:user_id, :term]).sum([:views, :clicks])
```

I know it's possible to use .group_by{} but it's not very efficient because it's aggregated by Ruby and not performed the query.

DB: Postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this

```
@reports = Report.select("reports.user_id, reports.term,
  sum(reports.views) as total_views
  sum(reports.clicks) as total_clicks").
  group("reports.user_id, reports.term")
```

please note all for total (as sum result) although they not show up, but they do exist if you call the name

```
@report.first # total_views and total_clicks not show up in rails console but
@report.first.total_views # you will see total calculation
```

Comment: Thanks for "not show up in rails console"! I lost so much time without this information.